# Subclassed NSArrayController bind to custom property

Tags: objective-c, nsarraycontroller

I am on XCode 10, Objective-C, Mac OSX, not iOS.

I have subclassed an NSArrayController to create a new property to bind to.

**SHArrayController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasItems;
```

**SHArrayController.m**

```
- (BOOL)hasItems
{
    return ([self.arrangedObjects count] > 0);
}
```

If i bind anything to that property i doesn't get notified of changes.
If i add an Object to the arrayController, "hasItems" should change.

This is how i add objects:

```
[self.arrayController willChangeValueForKey:@"hasItems"];
[self.arrayController addObject:SomeObject];
[self.arrayController didChangeValueForKey:@"hasItems"];
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit: ArrayController is properly instantiated, so are the objects to add.

Comment: How do you bind what to `hasItems`? How did you check if it gets notified of changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a fault of mine. The value did change and the notification works. I just made a mistake. The above implementation is correct.